# Scipy solve_ivp not giving expected solutions

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I need to solve a 2nd order ODE which I have decoupled into two first order ODEs. I've tried solving it using `solve_ivp`, but it doesn't seem to provide the solution I expect. I have provided the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import derivative
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex = True)

V0 = 2*10**-10
A = 0.130383
f = 0.129576
phi_i_USR2 = 6.1
phi_Ni_USR2 = 1.2

def V_USR2(phi):
    return V0*(np.tanh(phi/np.sqrt(6)) + A*np.sin(1/f*np.tanh(phi/np.sqrt(6))))**2

def V_phi_USR2(phi):
    return derivative(V_USR2, phi)

N = np.linspace(0,66,1000)
def USR2(N, X):
    phi, g = X
    return [g, (g**2/2 - 3)*(V_phi_USR2(phi)/V_USR2(phi) + g)]

X0 = [phi_i_USR2, phi_Ni_USR2]
sol = solve_ivp(USR2, (0,66), X0, method = 'LSODA', t_eval = N)
phi_USR2 = sol.y[0]
phi_N_USR2 = sol.y[1]
N_USR2 = sol.t
plt.plot(phi_USR2, phi_N_USR2)
plt.xlabel("$\phi$")
plt.ylabel("$\phi'$")
plt.title("Phase plot for USR2")
plt.show()
```

`solve_ivp` gives me the following plot:

[image]

The problem is that there is supposed to be an oscillation near the origin, which is not well captured by `solve_ivp`. However, for the same equation and initial conditions, Mathematica gives me exactly what I want:

[image]

I want the same plot in Python as well. I tried various methods in `solve_ivp` such as RK45, LSODA, Radau and BDF, but all of them show the same problem (LSODA tries to depict an oscillation but fails, but the other methods don't even move past the point where the oscillation starts). It would be great if someone can shed light on the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, your equation is `phi' = g` and `g' = (g**2/2 - 3) * (V'(phi)/V(phi) + g)`? And `V(phi)` is `V0 * (T + A*sin(T/f))**2` where `T=tanh(phi/sqrt(6))`. /// How exactly is `derivative(V,phi)` implemented? Did you try to adjust the tolerances? The signs in `g'` are correct, no global minus sign missing?

Comment: I used `scipy.misc.derivative` with the default spacing. Sorry for not clarifying earlier, I've added all module imports in the code. And yes, my equation is perfectly correct.

Comment: Read the documentation, default is `dx=1.0`. Explicitly set `dx=1e-5` to get an optimally exact derivative.

Comment: This problem is very sensible to how the division by zero in `dV/V` is handled. I get a plot similar to the last one by replacing that with `dV*V/(1e-26+V**2)` and extending `N` to `91` or larger.